# Does this query have to be optimal? If not Is there anyway to improve that query

Tags: mysql

I have wrote an SQL Query but I don't know it is best or not.

I have two tables, relationship is 1-n.

Order table

```
|---------------------|
|      orderNumber    | 
|---------------------|
|          status     |
|---------------------|
```

orderDetail

```
|---------------------|
|      orderNumber    | 
|---------------------|
|          quantity   |
|---------------------|
|       price         |
|---------------------|
```

I want to get order have status is `shipped` and totalPrice is greater than 1500 and totalPrice sort decending

```
SELECT * FROM order JOIN 
       (Select sub1.orderNumber, SUM(sub1.totalEach) AS total FROM (
          select (quantity * price) AS totalEach, orderNumber FROM orderDetail)
      AS sub1 GROUP BY sub1.orderNumber HAVING total > 1500 ORDER BY total DESC
      ) AS sub2 
      ON order.orderNumber = sub2.orderNumber 
      WHERE order.status = 'shipped'
```

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact
with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all 
you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the subquery; and approach this problem using `Inner join` between the two tables, and using `Group by` with `Having`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT o.orderNumber, 
       o.status, 
       SUM(od.quantity * od.price) AS total   
FROM order AS o 
JOIN orderDetail AS od ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber 
WHERE o.status = 'shipped' 
GROUP BY o.orderNumber, o.status 
HAVING total > 1500 
ORDER BY totalEach DESC
```

Comment: Oh I don't know we can use sum of calculated field in same time. Anw thank